# Gamma matrices relations (Dirac Spinors: QFT)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, spinors, dirac-matrices, clifford-algebra

The entry question in an exam paper: I think I have made an elementary error in the transpose somewhere invoked by a conceptual misunderstanding of how spinors behave with gamma matrices under a transpose.

> $u$ and $v$ are arbitrary Dirac spinors, and we define, $\bar{w} = w^\dagger\gamma^0$.
>
> Prove $(\bar{u}\gamma^\mu v)^* = \bar{v}\gamma^\mu u$.

I have the following,
$$
(\bar{u}\gamma^\mu v)^* = \bar{u}^*\gamma^{\mu*} v^* = (v^\dagger\gamma^{\mu\dagger}\bar{u}^\dagger)^T
$$

using $\gamma^{\mu\dagger} = \gamma^0\gamma^\mu\gamma^0$ and expanding $\bar{u}^\dagger = \gamma^0u$,

$$
(\bar{u}\gamma^\mu v)^* = \bar{u}^*\gamma^{\mu*} v^* = (v^\dagger\gamma^0\gamma^\mu\overbrace{\gamma^0\gamma^0}^{1}u)^T
 =
(\bar{v}\gamma^\mu u)^T
\ne
\bar{v}\gamma^\mu u
$$

However, I have still got a transpose flying around for some reason!

Comment: Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please read [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093).

Comment: @KyleKanos, Physics, and particularly theoretical physics, is a subject that is learned through practice. From the very link you referenced: *A blatant "spot my deliberate mistake" question is always going to be off topic, but I would urge site members to consider whether the mistake is conceptual rather than arithmetical. If it's a conceptual mistake I think there is some justification for answering the question as long as your answer is mainly concerned with the concepts involved* 

- This questions clearly demonstrates a misunderstanding that $\bar{v}\gamma^\mu u$ is, in fact, scalar.

Comment: Except you have shown *no* conceptual misunderstanding, just that you have been unable to get the right answer.

Comment: @KyleKanos In fact, almost every answer to both links suggests that the down vote is without merit. Despite being one of the most prolific down voters in Physics, I emplore you to consult your citations before using them. Clearly, the transpose is not the issue, rather, the result. Instead of writing a conflated post, it is better for the SE community to present a concise problem that led to the issue. To make this clearer for you I have edited a sentence into the question.

Comment: Downvotes are a free for all (danger with upvotes, for that matter). Assuming it is one particular use can be dangerous. Do you want a screenshot that it isn't?

Comment: And, both links say that we don't solve your homework problems here. The second simply requests us to look more closely at questions to see if the issue is a conceptual one; I see no concept error here.

Comment: I think it is clear from $(\bar{v}\gamma^\mu u)^T 
\ne
\bar{v}\gamma^\mu u$ that I am not aware that the relation is a scalar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First notice that $(\bar u\gamma^\mu v)$ is just a scalar, i.e. number. So taking a dagger would be the same as taking its complex conjugate.

So, $(\bar u\gamma^\mu v)^\dagger=v^\dagger(\gamma^\mu)^\dagger\gamma^0u=v^\dagger\gamma^0\gamma^0(\gamma^\mu)^\dagger\gamma^0u=\bar v\gamma^\mu u.$

Notice that I have inserted $\gamma^0\gamma^0 = 1$, and used that fact that, $\gamma^0 (\gamma^\mu)^\dagger \gamma^0 = \gamma^\mu$ and $(\gamma^0)^\dagger=\gamma^0.$